# LED lights turn on and off by themselves with buzz

Tags: led

I had someone replace my ceiling lights with LEDs. There are 10 lights on the circuit. After a while some of the lights will turn off and then turn on again. I haven't noticed any discernible pattern to it. The lights also buzz. They are on new LED compatible dimmer. I have the same issue on two different light circuits.

Update:
The buzzing happens when the lights are on regardless of what setting the dimmer is at (full or partial).
The LEDs are marked as dimmable the dimmer is marked as LED compatible.

Comment: I think the LEDs also need to dimable.

Comment: Check if the issue occurs when the dimmer is set on 100% bright -- if the LED lamps still buzz, the issue is likely *not* the dimmer, but if they *don't* buzz or flicker at full brightness, then they're not compatible with that dimmer. You can try replacing either the lights, or trying another dimmer, recognizing that the lights might not work with the new dimmer, or just replace the dimmer with an On/Off switch.

Comment: The LEDs are dimmable and the switch is dimmable LED friendly @crip659

Comment: @DrMoishePippik updated the question, if the switch isn't off then there is buzzing. I'm guessing the LEDs are not compatible with the switch :(

Comment: If the lights buzz even at 100% brightness, then it's possible there is another issue. You could temporarily replace the dimmer with an on/off switch to confirm that.